# Android: How do i display this image into a bitmap?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera, loading

What i'm doing/trying to do, is. 
1. Take a photo
2. Save it 
3. Load/display it into a Bitmap

Opening the Built in camera application:

```
public void openCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "image.jpg");
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        //Check that request code matches ours:
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
            //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
            Bitmap image = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
        }
    }
```

decodeSamoleBitmapFromFile:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

        //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight)
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
        {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }

        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

I was hoping for it to load it into a bitmap. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I can't seem to display the image into a bitmap

Comment: You decoded a bitmap. Where do you displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a Bitmap, you'll have to use an [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). Once you have both the bitmap and the reference to your `ImageView`, call `ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` to display your bitmap.